# Partial view not rendering on dropdownlist change

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview, cascadingdropdown

i have a drop down list that when a value is selected, a partial view rendering the relevant data is supposed to be shown. i have been at it for a few days as i'm new to this and can't seem to get it to work. help anyone.

INDEX

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Voyage Information"; }

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "VM", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId  = "VMResults" }))
{ 

<div id="container">  
    <label for="ddlvm"><strong>Select Vessel</strong></label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.Vessel_ID,(SelectList)ViewBag.ddl, "-- Select Vessel --", new {@id = 
    "ddlvm"}) 

    <br/><br/>

    <div id="VMResults">

    </div>
</div>  
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddlvm").change(function () {
         var vId = $("#ddlvm").val();
            $("#VMResults").load('@(Url.Action("GetVessel","VM",null, Request.Url.Scheme))?vId=' +  
    vId);
    });     
});
```

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.ddl = new SelectList(db.X_VesselMaster.OrderBy(x => x.Vessel_Name), "Vessel_ID", "Vessel_Name");
    return View();
}


[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetVessel(int y)  
{
    var viewModel = new VoyageData();
    viewModel.VesselMasters = db.X_VesselMaster.Where(i => i.Vessel_ID == (y)).Include(i => 
    i.X_Vessel_Transaction_Header).ToList();

    if (y != null)
    {
        viewModel.Vessel_Transaction_Headers = viewModel.VesselMasters.Single(i => i.Vessel_ID == 
    (y)).X_Vessel_Transaction_Header.Where(c => c.Deleted <= 0).ToList();
    }
    return PartialView("_Voyages", viewModel);

}
```

PARTIAL VIEW

```
@model ......
<table>  
    <thead>
    <tr><th>Vessel ID</th></tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Arrived</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    @foreach (var m in Model.Vessel_Transaction_Headers)
        {
           <tr><td>@m.Vessel_ID</td></tr> 

           <tr>
                <td>@m.Arrived</td>

                 </tr>
        }   

</table>
```

Comment: In your controller you expect a parameter called `y`, but you send a parameter `?vId=`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the javascript so that it submits the form that you have created. Use jquery to find it (if it's the only one, you can find it simply with `$form=$('form')`. If there are more than one you can specify an id for it (in the atrributes parameter of `Ajax.beginForm` helper) and look for it using the id, like this `$form = $('#theFormId')`. Once you get it selected witgh jQuery, simply unwrap the form DOM object, and call its submit method, like this: `$fomr[0].submit()`.

Once this happens, the unobtrusive ajax helpers will take care of posting the data in the form, and updating the VMResults id content.

The problem is that you're mixing up two technologies: pure ajax, and ASP.NET Ajax helpers and unobtrusive helpers.

If you want to do it using simply jQuery ajax, you don't need the form at all. Simply do somethign like this in your change event handler:

```
$("#ddlvm").change(function () {
  var vId = $("#ddlvm").val();
  jQuery.get('@(Url.Action("GetVessel","VM",null, Request.Url.Scheme))?vId=' + vId);
  }).done(function(html) {
    $('#VMResults').html(html);
  });
});
```

Please, note that you need to make the ajax call `get`, and then wait for the response, which is done in the `.done()` function. When your browser get the response from the server, the done callback will be invoked, passing as parameter the server response, which is your expected answer.

In a few words: do it either using ASP.NET MVC Ajax helpers or using pure jQuery and JavaScript ajax. At least, you now should be know that you're mixing up two different things.